# Sort string by date with multiple delimiters

Tags: python

I have a list of files that can be found by using the glob command. The prefix of the file name changes by the user (not a set format) but there is date within the file name. I would like to sort it by the date and return the latest one. If there is more than one file with the same date after the sorting, sort them by the last series of number.

I have looked up a few examples on slackoverflow. This example has the closest solution. [Sort by date and string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22467845/sort-by-date-and-string-in-python) . However, I have more than one _ delimiter, which makes it inefficient to split the string multiple time. Besides, user might use more than one _ delimiter. I'm looking for a better solution to extract last part of the string given that it is a fixed format and isn't affected by the user input prefix.

List of file names:

```
file_v1__2019-07-01-090001.dat
file_v1__2019-07-01-090201.dat
file_v1__2019-06-01-092301.dat
file_v1__2019-06-01-091001.dat
file_v1__2019-06-02-091021.dat
```

Comment: `sorted(dates, key=lambda d: d.split('_')[-1])` ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to sort them if all you want is the latest. To do this you need to be able extract the date, which can be done using a regular expression and use that as the `key` argument for the built-in `max()` function.

```
import re

files = '''
file_v1__2019-07-01-090001.dat
file_v1__2019-07-01-090201.dat
file_v1__2019-06-01-092301.dat
file_v1__2019-06-01-091001.dat
file_v1__2019-06-02-091021.dat
'''.split()

regex = re.compile(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{6}') # XXXX-XX-XX-XXXXXX Date pattern

print(max(files, key=lambda file:(regex.search(file).group(0))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split sort the array using sorted function. 
Assume the file names are stored in variable `file_list`

You can sort it using

```
sorted_file_list = sorted(file_list, key=lambda each_file: each_file.split('_')[-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

`date = sorted(date, key=lambda x: x.split('__')[-1])`